# How Do I Calculate The Evidence From Bayes Theorem

Tags: calculus, probability, bayes-theorem

In Bayesian Inference, we can calculate the evidence in one of two ways:

$$P(E) = \sum_k^K P(H=k)P(E|H=k)$$

or by:

$$P(E) = \int P(H)P(E|H) dz$$

We want the probability that our coin toss is fair, given the following data:

We flip a coin 5 times, and we get heads 3 times.

Our prior distribution can simply be the standard normal distribution.

$$P(H = 0.5|E) = \frac{P(E|H = 0.5) P(H=0.5)}{P(E)}$$

$$P(H = 0.5|E) = \frac{(_5C_3 * 0.5^3 * 0.5^5)* \frac{3}{5}}{P(E)}$$

How would I calculate P(E) in this example?

$$P(E) = P(H=0.5)P(E|H = 0.5) + P(H \neq 0.5)P(E|H \neq 0.5)$$

This is my general misunderstanding with Bayesian Inference. I understand that sometimes the Evidence can be intractable to calculate, but what information would I need here to be able to actually compute the sum or the integral of the Evidence? I'm not even sure how the math for an integral over probabilities would even look.

Comment: In Baysian inference, you need a prior. Without your prior distribution for $H$, nothing can be said. That distribution could be discrete or continuous. But it has to be an entire distribution for $H$, it can’t just be probabilities for $H=0.5$ and $H\ne0.5$, because there’s no such thing as $P(E\mid H\ne0.5)$. (More precisely, you could calculate $P(E\mid H\ne0.5)$ if you specify a distribution for $H$, but you can't calculate it just from $P(H=0.5)$ and $P(H\ne0.5)$.)

Comment: So I could assume that my prior distribution is simply the standard normal distribution correct? If so, how could I calculate the evidence from that prior? I'll update my question such that it is more computable.